# Why DOMDocument::schemaValidate() over the same XML and XSD files have sometimes a execution time dramatically higher than usual?

Tags: php, xml, xsd, domdocument, execution-time

It is extrange that a default class method fails that way, sometimes, even when the arguments passed to the method are the same that usualy takes a fraction of second.

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   *script_path*
>   on line *script_line_number*

In that exact line:

`$result = $DOMDocument -> schemaValidate($schemaPath);`

$DOMDocument is always the same. And it only references parts of the same XML with ID atrtibutes. It does not have any URL like attribute, besides Algorith and xmlns ones, which by nature does not call anyresource from anywhere, and we are talking about DOMDocument class of PHP and the XML starndards.

`$schemaPath` is always the same, and it is pointing to a server local XSD file, which is always there, before, and after the validation attempt, either it is successful or not. The schema is only pointing to other local xsd files, located in the same folder i.e. `<xs:include schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>`

The only possible answer I can think of, is that the XSD file is located by the method but for some reason it cannot be read, because the disc is busy.

What could be causing the execution of the method take so long?

What measures should be taken to prevent the error to happen besides increasing the maximum execution time limit of PHP?

The XML and the XSD files are pretty small, in fact the exact same XML and XSD usually takes less than ~ 0.1 seconds to validate, but a very few times (~ 1 out of 1000) the execution time exeeds 30 seconds.

---

**EDIT**

I isolated the problem so I post a samples.

Schema.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.foo.bar/Car" xmlns:SiiDte="http://www.foo.bar/Car" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsignature_v10.xsd"/><!-- just the standar signature schema -->
    <xs:element name="ROOT" type="SiiDte:ROOTDefType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ROOTDefType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Element"></xs:element>
            <xs:element ref="ds:Signature">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Firma Digital sobre Documento</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:decimal" use="required" fixed="1.0"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Schema2.xsd:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.foo.bar/Car" xmlns:ns1="http://www.foo.bar/Car" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:simpleType name="MOOType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Code:

```
// ... a bunch of ther code...

$XML =
    '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ROOT xmlns="http://www.foo.bar/Car" version="1.0">
        <Element ID="A1">hello</Element>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <Reference URI="#A1">
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <DigestValue>base64string</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>base64string</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <KeyValue>
                    <RSAKeyValue>
                        <Modulus>base64string</Modulus>
                        <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
                    </RSAKeyValue>
                </KeyValue>
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>base64string</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
    </ROOT>'
;

$DD = new DOMDocument();
$DD -> loadXML($XML);
$i = 0;

while ($i < 100) {
    // ... a bunch of other code...

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $old_libxml_disable_entity_loader = libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);        $result = $DD -> schemaValidate(__DIR__ . '/schema.xsd');
    libxml_disable_entity_loader($old_libxml_disable_entity_loader); // Se desactiva nuevamente carga de entidades para descartar entidades maliciosas
    $i++;
    echo str_pad($i, 5) . ($result ? 'true' : 'false') . '<br>';

    // ... a bunch of other code...
}
```

Comment: `XSD file is located by the method but for some reason it cannot be read, because the disc is busy` - or does it need something from the net which isn't available at that time?

Comment: The script does not interact with the client, the client only executes it, all the data is stored in the server. Anyways what you suggest does not matter, because the schema is always located in same path in the server filesystem, and if the XML was malformed, or not a DOMDocument, another error should happen once at the schemaValidation line (*script_line_number*), not this one.

Comment: and the schema itself doesn't require anything else ...from the net?

Comment: no, it is just a text like any other stored in the filesystem, they are not referencing any resource in the net. also i have `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', false);` for security. The schema only references local files stored in the same folder (e.g.: `<xs:include schemaLocation="other_schema.xsd"/>`).

Comment: afaik, `<xsd:include/import schemaLocation="http://..."` wouldn't be affected by allow_url_fopen=false. But anyway, if you say there's no inet resource involved, let's consider it ruled out ;-)

Comment: You may also see this behavior if your XML, XSD or other XML documents contain a DTD with a public identifier, for instance the XHTML DTD. A validating XML reader will attempt to read that file. If that is the case, remove DTD validation, add a URI resolver that resolves the URIs locally (plus store DTD locally) or simply remove the DTD declaration, you won't need it, you use schema.

Comment: Or, if you have a `schemaLocation` attribute that does not use the paired tokens (space separate, in pairs, URI and location), possibly letting the parser think it should treat it as a location. Some XSD parsers are known to do this, though technically such attribute is wrong.

Comment: Neither does the XML, it does not have any attribute referencing anything outside itself, it only have attributes xmlns, Algorithm, with URL like strings, but these attributes does not call anything by nature.

Comment: @Abel, the schema location is `<xs:include schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>`, i.e. referencing a xsd located in the same folder. It is not separated in pairs, but the validation 99% of the time executes successfuly under 0.1 seconds, with exactly same XML and schemas

Comment: @mikl, I didn't mean that one. I meant the referenced schema, or the XML you are validating, which contains a `schemaLocation` attribute in the root. Have you checked there?

Comment: @Abel, there are three chained schemas in total, none of them reference anything in the net, the same way i described with $DOMDocument, schema.xsd and schema2.xsd

Comment: If you don't have external parsed entities, no dtd declaration anywhere, if you checked network traffic with a sniffer, then the only other thing I can think of is a thread lock issue, the rarity of this occurrence suggests this. Other than out of process I don't know how to fix that, it can be a bug in PHP, the libraries or other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that the whole script is reaching the 30 seconds mark, not a DOMDocument::schemaValidate() execution alone.

The execution time corresponds to the full script executing, with all its includes and iterations in case it has.

Consider the execution time does not count any time spent outside the script, such as in stream operations, database queries, amongst others. So for example the script may look as taking 1 minut when in reality it is taking only 15 or 30. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php which states:

> Note: The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

It is not ::schemaValidate() which is taking 30 seconds to execute, it is the full script. Then why once the script reach 30 seconds the error falls just inside schemaValidate()? Because altought ::schemaValidate() it is a relatively fast method to execute, it must be the most complex code inside the iteration, hence the biggest chance is the error falls when schemaValidate is executing, after N repetitions (in the real case N must be a lot).

So the answer is ::schemaValidate() is consuming most of the execution time, hence the error ocurs virtualy always when ::schemaValidate() is executing.